# If $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$ and $\arg z_1\leq \arg z_2 \leq \arg z_3$ prove that $\arg{\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}}=\frac{1}{2}\arg \frac{z_2}{z_1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

If $z_1,z_2,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$ and $\arg z_1\leq \arg z_2 \leq \arg z_3$ prove that $$\arg{\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}}=\frac{1}{2}\arg \frac{z_2}{z_1}$$

Answer: $\ \arg z_1= \varphi_1,\ \arg z_2= \ \varphi_2, \ \arg z_3=\varphi_3\ldots$

The answer comes to the point where:

$$\arg\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}=\arg\left(e^{i \frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}{2}}\frac{\sin{\frac{\varphi_3-\varphi_2}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{\varphi_3-\varphi_1}{2}}}\right)= \text{ (this part is not clear)}\\$$

> $$ = \arg e^{i \frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}{2}}+\arg
>  \frac{\sin{\frac{\varphi_3-\varphi_2}{2}}}{\sin\frac{\varphi_3-\varphi_1}{2}}=\arg
>  e^{i \frac{\varphi_1-\varphi_2}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\arg \frac{z_2}{z_1}$$

Answer (score 2):

think of the points $z_1,z_2,z_3$ as points $P,Q,R$ on the circumference of a circle centered at the origin.

a well-known theorem of Euclidean geometry gives:
$$
Q\hat O R = 2 Q\hat PR
$$
from which the result follows

Comment: Could you please go into more detail if it is not a problem. I agree with what you state here, but how does that justify my unclear line in the problem?